# Correcting cumulatives in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that has the following columns:

> **DeviceId** | **Timestamp** | **Total_Data**
>    001          08/12/2014     500
>    001          08/13/2014     600
>    001          08/14/2014     750
>    001          08/15/2014     150 (device restarted here) (correct value:750+150)
>    001          08/16/2014     300 (correct value: 750+150+300)
>    002          10/01/2014     98
>   ...
>   ..

For a bunch of different devices, I have the data they consumed on different occasions (noted by the timestamps).

The **Total_Data** column is cumulative in nature and therefore, for a given device, calculates the total data consumed over time. For example, if device A used 3KB on `12 August 2012` and 5KB on `14 August 2012`, the DataFrame would have two entries with the second entry having its **Total_Data** value as 8KB.

The glitch however, is that the cumulative values reset to 0 (and started counting again) when the devices were rebooted. And therefore, need to be corrected. What would be the best way to alter my current DataFrame in Pandas to solve this problem

Until now, I've thought of iterating through the DataFrame on a row by row basis but it just seems too complex.

Comment: You could replace the `0` values with `NaN`, then forward fill them, also it's useful to post data and code, see [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html#pandas.Series.fillna), so I think something like `df['Total_Data'].replace(0, NaN)` and then `df['Total_Data'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)` I think should work

Comment: Do you have sample data (dataframe) for us to look at

Comment: Updated question with an example DataFrame.

@EdChum When the value resets to 0 doesn't mean it's actually 0. It means that it starts counting the data usage cumulatively from 0 again. (see example)

Comment: How do we know the device wasn't rebooted every morning?  IOW, how do we know the corrected Total_Data column shouldn't start 500, 1100, etc.?  Is there another Series with this information?

Comment: The restarted value can be anything. Generally if the series is increasing and then drops, that means the phone was restarted. While this is hard to ascertain, it's a reasonable assumption with this data set.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's the code sample solving your issue.
I assumed that if there was a reboot, then the TotalData value is less than previous value.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.Series([datetime(2014, 8, 12),
                                      datetime(2014, 8, 13),
                                      datetime(2014, 8, 14),
                                      datetime(2014, 8, 15),
                                      datetime(2014, 8, 16)]),
                   'TotalData': pd.Series([500, 600, 750, 150, 300])
                   })
df['PrevTotalData'] = df['TotalData'].shift(1)
df.loc[0, 'PrevTotalData'] = 0

# Assuming here that the amount of data day after reboot is always less then
# the total amount of data in previous day
rebooted = df['PrevTotalData'] > df['TotalData']
df['DataBeforeLastReboot'] = 0
df.ix[rebooted, 'DataBeforeLastReboot'] = df['PrevTotalData']
df['DataBeforeLastReboot'] = df['DataBeforeLastReboot'].cumsum()
df['TotalDataFixed'] = df['TotalData'] + df['DataBeforeLastReboot']

print(df)
```

The data frame before:

```
        Date  TotalData
0 2014-08-12        500
1 2014-08-13        600
2 2014-08-14        750
3 2014-08-15        150
4 2014-08-16        300
```

And after:

```
        Date  TotalData  PrevTotalData  DataBeforeLastReboot  TotalDataFixed
0 2014-08-12        500              0                     0             500
1 2014-08-13        600            500                     0             600
2 2014-08-14        750            600                     0             750
3 2014-08-15        150            750                   750             900
4 2014-08-16        300            150                   750            1050
```

In case the the data frame consists of different machines, the solution is a bit more complex.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


df = pd.DataFrame({'Machine': pd.Series([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
                   'Date': pd.Series([datetime(2014, 8, 12),
                                      datetime(2014, 8, 13),
                                      datetime(2014, 8, 14),
                                      datetime(2014, 8, 15),
                                      datetime(2014, 8, 16),
                                      datetime(2014, 8, 12),
                                      datetime(2014, 8, 13),
                                      datetime(2014, 8, 14),
                                      datetime(2014, 8, 15),
                                      datetime(2014, 8, 16)]),
                   'TotalData': pd.Series([500, 600, 750, 150, 300,
                                           100, 200, 300, 100, 200])
                   })
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.set_index(['Machine', 'Date'])
grouped_by_machine = df.groupby(level=[0])
df['PrevTotalData'] = grouped_by_machine['TotalData'].shift(1)
df['PrevTotalData'] = df['PrevTotalData'].fillna(value=0)

# Assuming here that the amount of data day after reboot is always less then
# the total amount of data in previous day
rebooted = df['PrevTotalData'] > df['TotalData']
df['DataBeforeLastReboot'] = 0
df.ix[rebooted, 'DataBeforeLastReboot'] = df['PrevTotalData']
df['DataBeforeLastReboot'] = grouped_by_machine['DataBeforeLastReboot'].cumsum()
df['TotalDataFixed'] = df['TotalData'] + df['DataBeforeLastReboot']
print(df)
```

Data frame before:

```
                    TotalData
Machine Date                 
0       2014-08-12        500
        2014-08-13        600
        2014-08-14        750
        2014-08-15        150
        2014-08-16        300
1       2014-08-12        100
        2014-08-13        200
        2014-08-14        300
        2014-08-15        100
        2014-08-16        200
```

and after:

```
                    TotalData  PrevTotalData  DataBeforeLastReboot  TotalDataFixed
Machine Date                                                                      
0       2014-08-12        500              0                     0             500
        2014-08-13        600            500                     0             600
        2014-08-14        750            600                     0             750
        2014-08-15        150            750                   750             900
        2014-08-16        300            150                   750            1050
1       2014-08-12        100              0                     0             100
        2014-08-13        200            100                     0             200
        2014-08-14        300            200                     0             300
        2014-08-15        100            300                   300             400
        2014-08-16        200            100                   300             500
```

Comment: Great solution! I'm curious to understand how I will incorporate this on a per device basis though. Because I need to do this for every device id.

Comment: Updated an answer to handle calculating separately for each device

Comment: Pavel, if I wish to find the last row in each group after this correction, do I just do a groupby? How would I do that?

Comment: Basically, for every device, I'd like to get the final cumulative sum

Comment: last_rows = grouped_by_machine.tail(1)

Comment: But I think the corrected TotalDataFixed is in "df". Shouldn't we be looking at that? Also, head(1) gives the first row; not the last.

Something like: df.groupby(['machine', 'time']).tail(1)?

Comment: And grouped_by_machine object is already grouped, so no need to group it again. Just paste the line from my previous comment at the end of the code from ny answer, and see that it works.

Answer (score 0):

1. First divide your Dataframe according to your reset
2. Make cumulative sum in each part
3. Add extra value from previous part

Code is given below:

```
grouped = df.groupby((df.TotalData.diff() <= 0).cumsum())
parts = [g.reset_index(drop=True) for k, g in grouped]


for i in range(1, len(parts)):
    parts[i]['TotalData']=parts[i]['TotalData'].cumsum().add(parts[i-1]['TotalData'].max())

DF = pd.concat(parts)

print DF
```

Result:

```
           Date  TotalData
   0 2014-08-12        500
   1 2014-08-13        600
   2 2014-08-14        750
   0 2014-08-15        900
   1 2014-08-16       1200
```